# Spring & Docker: request was rejected because URL was not normalized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, nginx

I have two docker containers that need to communicate with each other. One is an nginx container for the front-end which needs to communicate to the Spring back-end in the other container.  The communication works fine when running outside of Docker, but when I dockerize the projects, I get the following error when attempting to send any requests from the front-end to the back-end:

```
 org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized.
```

from Spring's StrictHttpFirewall.

nginx.conf

```
load_module "modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so";
env HELIUM_LOCATION;

http {
    perl_set $helium_location 'sub { return $ENV{"HELIUM_LOCATION"}; }';

    server {
        listen 8000;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        client_max_body_size 10M;

        location /api {
            rewrite ^/api(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /api;
            proxy_pass http://$helium_location;
        }

        location /health {
             default_type application/json;
             return 200 '{"status": "UP"}';
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
 }
```

The Spring boot version is 2.1 and the nginx container is nginx:1.11.8-alpine. This works when using Spring boot 1.5.7 so did something change with how Spring handles these requests?

If there is any other information that would be helpful in solving this, let me know and I'll get it for you as best I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [Spring Framework Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#request-matching)

> For example, it could contain path-traversal sequences (like /../) or
>   multiple forward slashes (//) which could also cause pattern-matches
>   to fail.

You're adding an extra slash with this rewrite

```
location /api {
    rewrite ^/api(.*) /$1 break;
    ...
}
```

On logs I can see this

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2019:16:22:15 +0000] "GET //something HTTP/1.0" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.52.1"
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2019:16:22:15 +0000] "GET /api/something HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.52.1"
```

Change it to

```
rewrite ^/api(.*) $1 break;
```

You can reload the configuration by doing `nginx -s reload`

Now is not prepending extra slashes

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2019:16:27:22 +0000] "GET /something HTTP/1.0" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.52.1"
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2019:16:27:22 +0000] "GET /api/something HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.52.1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I grabbed a line from the logs and it doesn't look like that is the issue:
    sms_qa.phosphorus | 10.1.2.22 - - [06/Mar/2019:18:01:17 +0000] "POST /api/auth HTTP/1.1" 401 0 "http://10.1.1.101:81/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"

Somewhere along the line that must be being handled already

Comment: did you try removing the extra slash in that rewrite?

Comment: Yes.  When I did that, the requests weren't making it to the back-end.  So apparently the app is depending on the slash somewhere along the line.